# inherit from two classes in c++ and inserting into list

Tags: c++

Is the following code problamatic regarding inserting into a list an object that inherits from two classes?

```
class A
{
}

class B
{
}

class C : public A, public B
{

}

C *myObj = new C();
std::list<A*> myList;
myList.push_front(myObj);
```

Is creating a list of type A and inserting an object of type C which is part of type B problematic?
I know this code compiles but I am affrade of memory issues.
If its a problem, what other options do I have to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the list stores the data by reference or pointer and the destructor is virtual you're fine.

The basic problem is that you are not allowed to store a C into a variable of `A`, but you can store it into `A&` or `A*`. So `A a = C()` would be just as bad as storing a C into a `list<A>` or `vector<A>`. This would lead to [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Comment: The list stores a pointer to C. Is that ok? At the end I pass the list to a function which expects a list of type *A
Why there will be a problem if it was a vector and not a list?

Comment: @Shay `vector` vs `list` is irrelevant, what he means is if you store values, instead of pointers, slicing will occur. Also, deleting an object via the base class destructor, if that destructor is not `virtual` is undefined behavior, regardless of whether the destructor is trivial or not. So `A` needs to have a `virtual` destructor, and probably `B` as well.

Comment: I think I understood - there wont be a problem because the list only allocates the address. And if the function which receives the list only calles A functions, there wont be a problem, right?

Comment: @Shay That is correct, and the function could also downcast the object to a `C*` type and call functions of class C. You can use `dynamic_cast` to test whether the cast was successful. And I meant to say *deleting an object via a base class pointer ...* in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, as long as you add references or pointers of the objects to the list in order to avoid slicing and have virtual destructors you should be safe.

You could think of `A` and `B` as being interfaces to the polymorphic type. Take a look at this example:

```
class Drawable
{
    public:
        virtual ~Drawable() { }
        virtual void draw();
};

class Circle : public Drawable
{
    public:
        void draw() { std::cout << "Drawing a circle\n"; }
}

class Square : public Drawable
{
    public:
        void draw() { std::cout << "Drawing a square\n"; }
}

int main()
{
    std::list<Drawable*> shapeList { new Square(), new Circle(), new Square() };
}
```